# EJB 3 Stateless bean pass data to interceptor

Tags: ejb-3.0, interceptor

How to pass data from stateless session bean to the method level interceptor for the current request. For each client request we need to have its own local data and should not conflict.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data to & from interceptors, you can try looking at methods of `InvocationContext` interface.

> **# java.lang.Object[] getParameters :** Returns the parameter values that will be passed to the method of the target class.
>
> **# setParameters(java.lang.Object[] params) :** Sets the parameter values that will be passed to the method of the target class.

Therefore, if you want to pass some data to interceptor, you can pass it as parameter & fetch them later in interceptor. Again, after processing, you can set appropriate data as parameter, which will be received by the final method.

Comment: i was asking about passing data from interceptor to ejb . and then ejb add some parameter and send to interceptor.

Comment: @SureshSankar I have mentioned that only, through method parameters, you can send/receive data among interceptor/EJB.